# Write a pyspark dataframe to Postgres without marking columns not null

Tags: python, postgresql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using the following code in python to write a Dataframe to Postgres:

```
df.write.format('jdbc') \
                .mode('append') \
                .option('url', url) \
                .option('dbtable', tn) \
                .option('user', un) \
                .option('password', pwd) \
                .option('driver', driver) \
                .save()
```

The code creates a new table and inserts the data as expected. The issue is that columns are marked as `not null` in Postgres. Is there a way to make them NOT `not null`?

Comment: Add a row of nulls at the end of the dataframe and remove it afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a baseline, this should be inherited from your Spark DataFrame. You can check the nullability by using `df.printSchema()`.

In terms of the nullability of columns in Postgres, I think you need to specify this on table creation in Postgres (if writing to existing table), or in Spark JDBC options and properties. That way, you would set a custom schema in your properties, e.g.

```
# Specifying create table column data types on write
jdbcDF.write \
    .option("createTableColumnTypes", "name CHAR(64), comments VARCHAR(1024)") \
    .jdbc("jdbc:postgresql:dbserver", "schema.tablename",
          properties={"user": "username", "password": "password"})
```

Here you could specify (if your JDBC allows it) the nullability, such as

```
option("createTableColumnTypes", "name CHAR(64) default null")
```

Alternatively, use the `createSchema` option (not sure if that would work with existing table, looking at your `append` option) - have a look at all options in https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html

Alternatively alternatively, create your table with a specific schema (and its nullability) explicitly ahead of time in Postgres.

Comment: Was able to go with alternative 2 - modify the schema `StructField(, , True)`